# What’s most simple way to sync ~/.vimrc?

Tags: linux, ssh, vim

I’m using SSH and Bash more and more. I continue to train with vim to improve automation. Customizing the configuration file `~/.vimrc` greatly helps.

I am very interested in the question: Is it possible to automate the synchronization of **.vimrc** with a remote server **via SSH** session or other methods?

Comment: It's possible to send .vimrc to the remote server using scp, sftp, rsync, sshfs etc. You may automate it by keeping your .vimrc in the Git repository and creating a commit-hook that would deploy the new .vimrc on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arkadiusz-drabczyk already stated, there are many different ways to do that.

The probably easiest solution is `scp ~/.vimrc USER@SERVER:PORT/home/USER/.vimrc` to copy the local file to the remote machine.

But to keep them in sync it's recommended to use a version control system, since you might perform changes both locally and on the remote.  This can be accomplished by either using a `git` repository and cloning it from a shared server (either a publicly available one like `gitlab.com` or similar) or from [creating a bare git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-do-you-use-git-bare-init-repository) on the remote server you are connecting to and using this for sharing the files.

A more advanced way to do that is to [utilize GNU Stow for dotfile management](https://alexpearce.me/2016/02/managing-dotfiles-with-stow/).  But several other dotfile management tools exist next to [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), like [rcm](https://github.com/thoughtbot/rcm), [yadm](https://yadm.io/), [homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick), [homeshick](https://github.com/andsens/homeshick), [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) and several others [(I'd recommend to take a look at the archwiki-page on that topic)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles).